# renaming file when uploading with django modelform

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm new to django and currently following a tutorial where it uses a ModelForm for a User Profile where a user can upload an avatar. I want to be able to update the file that they upload to a generated id. I'm just not sure where and how to do capture and update the file.

My Model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(default='avatar_default.jpg', upload_to='profile_images')

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.avatar.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300,300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.avatar.path)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

Form

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['avatar']
```

View

```
@login_required
def user_profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, 
                                        request.FILES, 
                                        instance=request.user.profile)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your profile has been updated')
            return redirect('users_profile')

    else:
        user_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    }

    return render(request, "users/profile.html", context)
```

I tried to apply some recommendations online where you do a Commit=False when saving the form and store that in a variable and renaming the file, it was a whole lot of confusion in the end.

Comment: I do not fully understand. Do you want it to be automatically saved with a name when uploading, or do you want to manually name the image when uploading? Or do you have a problem with the location where the image will be saved?

Comment: i want to manually name the image with a specific format when uploading